# How to preserve viewstate of textbox on postback when ajax is used ?

Tags: c#

I have created the webpage `default.aspx` inherited from Master page. I have used ajax **update panel** on default.aspx.

There are **3 textboxes** on default page. When I click on submit, the error occured on the page and there is link *Show Error* which redirects to `showError.aspx` which shows the error details.

On `showError.aspx` page there is back button which onclick return back to `default.aspx`. In this process it *looses the viewstate* of *textboxes* at default page.

So how can I preserve the viewstate when ajax is used ?

Comment: do you have all controls on update panel?? explain this question little more to understand better..

Answer (score 0):

this is typical behavior for webforms. viewstate is valid between postbacks. meaning you are posting to the same page(url). if you leave that page and go to another, then you are abandoning viewstate. the next time you return to that page viewstate is reset. the server doesn't know how you got the page (address bar, html button/link, or using history). it just knows you did arrive.

the short answer is you don't preserve viewstate. doing so defeats the purpose of viewstate. it's only meant to exist between postbacks. There are ways to preserve the user input, but this may require conceptual and design changes to how you are managing the validate and errors.

for example.
1. validate the user input (required, range, regex, etc.
2. validate the business rules (customer is valid, date is after point in time, customer's account is not on hold, etc)
3. process the request.

1 & 2 should catch most problems and return the user to the same page, with fields populated and a list of errors why the request was not successful.
If an error occurs at #3 then it's truly exceptional and should abandon all work. the user shouldn't return to the previous page with state preserved because something really is wrong that you were not expecting.

and all of this is indifferent of what the input is and whether or not you use ajax.

Comment: Jason, I have used the ajaxupdatepanel inside that I have some textboxes, submit button and showError Link on default page. When I click on submit the error occurs then I click on showError Link and I redirect to custom error page. After that on error page I have button Back onclick it return back to the default page. Now viewstate of textboxes is lost.